# I keep getting "undefined" although it is defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, undefined

I keep getting 'spell' is not defined.

Please keep in mind I am very new at this. I've mostly been following a tutorial class in Udemy.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\RealD\PycharmProjects\PythonRPGgame\main.py", line 106, in <module>
    player.reduce_mp(spell.cost)
NameError: name 'spell' is not defined
```

I have defined 'spell' in a separate class file which I've imported into the main.py script

magic.py

```
class Spell:
    def __init__(self, name, cost, dmg, type):
        self.name = name
        self.cost = cost
        self.dmg = dmg
        self.type = type

    def generate_damage(self):
        low = self.dmg - 15
        high = self.dmg + 15
        return random.randrange(low, high)
```

the error is said to be here:

```
player.reduce_mp(spell.cost)
```

inventory.py

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, type, descrip, prop):
        # descrip meaning description
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        self.descrip = descrip
        self.prop = prop
```

game.py

```
import random
from classes.inventory import Item
import pprint

class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'


class Person:
    def __init__(self, hp, mp, atk, df, magic, items):
        self.maxhp = hp
        self.hp = hp
        self.maxmp = mp
        self.mp = mp
        self.atkl = atk - 10
        self.atkh = atk + 10
        self.df = df
        self.magic = magic
        self.items = items
        self.action = ["Attack", "Magic", "Items"]

    def generate_damage(self):
        return random.randrange(self.atkl, self.atkh)

    def heal(self, dmg):
        self.hp += dmg
        if self.hp > self.maxhp:
            self.hp = self.maxhp

    '''def generate_spell_damage(self, i):
        mgl = self.magic[i]["dmg"] - 5
        mgh = self.magic[i]["dmg"] + 5
        return random.randrange(mgl, mgh)'''

    def take_damage(self, dmg):
        self.hp -= dmg
        if self.hp < 0:
            self.hp = 0
        return self.hp

    def get_hp(self):
        return self.hp

    def get_max_hp(self):
        return self.maxhp

    def get_mp(self):
        return self.mp

    def get_max_mp(self):
        return self.maxmp

    def reduce_mp(self, cost):
        self.mp -= cost

    def choose_action(self):
        i = 1
        print("\n" + bcolors.BOLD + bcolors.HEADER + "ACTIONS:" + bcolors.ENDC)
        for item in self.action:
            print("    " + str(i) + ". ", item)
            i += 1

    def choose_magic(self):
        i = 1
        print("\n" + bcolors.OKBLUE + bcolors.BOLD + "MAGIC:" + bcolors.ENDC)
        for spell in self.magic:
            print("    " + str(i) + ". ", spell.name, "(cost:", str(spell.cost) + ")")
            i += 1

    def choose_item(self):
        i = 1

        print("\n" + bcolors.OKGREEN + bcolors.BOLD + "ITEMS:" + bcolors.ENDC)
        for item in self.items:
            print(("    " + str(i)) + ". " , item["item"].name, ":", item["item"].descrip, " (x" + str(item["quantity"]) + ")")
            i += 1
```

Main.py:

```
from classes.game import Person, bcolors
from classes.magic import Spell
from classes.inventory import Item
import re


fire = Spell("Fire", 10, 100, "black")
thunder = Spell("Thunder", 10, 100, "black")
blizzard = Spell("Blizzard", 10, 100, "black")
meteor = Spell("Meteor", 10, 100, "black")
quake = Spell("Quake", 14, 140, "black")


cure = Spell("Cure", 12, 120, "white")
cura = Spell("Cura", 18, 200, "white")


potion = Item("Potion", "potion", "Heals 50 HP", 50)
hipotion = Item("Hi-Potion", "potion", "Heals 100 HP", 50)
superpotion = Item("Super Potion", "potion", "Heals 500 HP", 500)
elixer = Item("Elixer", "elixer", "Fully restores HP/MP of one party member", 9999)
hielixer = Item("Super Elixer", "elixer", "Fully restores entire party's HP/MP", 9999)


grenade = Item("Grenade", "attack", "Deals 500 damage", 500)

player_spells = [fire, thunder, blizzard, meteor, quake, cure, cura]
player_items = [{"item": potion, "quantity": 15}, {"item": hipotion, "quantity": 5},
                {"item": superpotion, "quantity": 5},  {"item":elixer, "quantity": 5},
                {"item": hielixer, "quantity": 2}, {"item": grenade, "quantity": 5}]


player = Person(460, 65, 60, 34, player_spells, player_items)
enemy = Person(1200, 65, 45, 25, [], [])






running = True
i = 0



print(bcolors.FAIL + bcolors.BOLD + " AN ENEMY ATTACKS!" + bcolors.ENDC)
print(bcolors.BOLD, bcolors.HEADER + "Press 0 to go back to the previous menu" + bcolors.ENDC)

while running:

    print("===============================")
    player.choose_action()
    choice = input(bcolors.BOLD + "Choose action:" + bcolors.ENDC)
    print("===============================")
    index = int(choice) - 1

    if index == 0:
        dmg = player.generate_damage()
        enemy.take_damage(dmg)
        print("===============================")
        print(bcolors.FAIL + "You attacked for", dmg, "points of damage!" + bcolors.ENDC)
    elif index == 1:
        player.choose_magic()
        magic_choice = int(input("Choose Magic: ")) - 1
        if magic_choice == -1:
            continue

        spell = player.magic[magic_choice]
        magic_dmg = player.magic[magic_choice].generate_damage()

        current_mp = player.get_mp()

        if spell.cost > current_mp:
            print(bcolors.FAIL + "\nNot enough MP\n" + bcolors.ENDC)
            continue

        if spell.type == "white":
            player.heal(magic_dmg)
            print(bcolors.OKBLUE + "\n" + spell.name + "heals for", str(magic_dmg), "HP" + bcolors.ENDC)
        elif spell.type == "black":
            enemy.take_damage(magic_dmg)
            print(bcolors.OKBLUE + "\n" + spell.name + "deals", str(magic_dmg), "points of damage!" + bcolors.ENDC)
    elif index == 2:
        player.choose_item()
        item_choice = int(input("Choose item: ")) - 1

        if item_choice == -1:
            continue

        item = player.items[item_choice]["item"]
        player.items[item_choice]["quantity"] -= 1


        if item.type == "potion":
            player.heal(item.prop)
            print(bcolors.OKGREEN + "\n" + item.name + " heals for", str(item.prop), "HP" + bcolors.ENDC)
        elif item.type == "elixer":
            player.hp = player.maxhp
            player.mp = player.maxmp
            print(bcolors.OKGREEN + "\n" + item.name + " fully restores HP/MP" + bcolors.ENDC)
        elif item.type == "attack":
            enemy.take_damage(item.prop)
            print(bcolors.FAIL + "\n" + item.name + " deals", str(item.prop), " points of damage" + bcolors.ENDC)



        player.reduce_mp(spell.cost)
        enemy.take_damage(magic_dmg)
        print(bcolors.OKBLUE + "\n" + spell.name + " deals", str(magic_dmg), "points of damage!" + bcolors.ENDC)


    enemy_choice = 1

    enemy_dmg = enemy.generate_damage()
    player.take_damage(enemy_dmg)
    print(bcolors.FAIL + "Enemy attacks for", enemy_dmg, "points of damage!" + bcolors.ENDC)

    print("===============================")
    print("Enemy HP:", bcolors.FAIL + str(enemy.get_hp()) + "/" + str(enemy.get_max_hp()) + bcolors.ENDC + "\n")

    print("Your HP:", bcolors.OKGREEN + str(player.get_hp()) + "/" + str(player.get_max_hp()) + bcolors.ENDC + "\n")
    print("Your MP:", bcolors.OKBLUE + str(player.get_mp()) + "/" + str(player.get_max_mp()) + bcolors.ENDC)

    if enemy.get_hp() == 0:
        print(bcolors.OKGREEN + "You won the battle!" + bcolors.ENDC)
        running = False
    elif player.get_hp() == 0:
        print(bcolors.FAIL + "You have died." + bcolors.ENDC)
        running = False
```

Comment: You sure it not just the missing capital letter? If not please post you main.py

Comment: You defined `Spell` not `spell`, character case is important.

Comment: The line with the error is not part of the code you pasted. Show the code where the that line is. BTW, a spoiler: if Python says it is not defined, then it is not defined.

Comment: Problem is not capitals. I had no problem with it earlier relating to capitals.

Also I'm sorry for adding everything in the code. Still new and am not really sure what is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like "spell" is defined in the branch where index == 1.  But the error is coming from the branch where index == 2.  If that branch is taken first, spell will still be undefined at that point.

I suspect the problem line is mislocated and you shouldn't be charging a spell cost when you've used an item instead.

Comment: it stays undefined throughout all the indexes. I'm just not sure why it's undefined itself if it is in magic.py. The code used to work just fine until I added an item system.

Comment: No, spell is defined (only) in the index == 1 branch.  `        spell = player.magic[magic_choice]`.  You cannot use that variable until after it is defined.

Comment: Can you address my other point?  Why are you decrementing MP for the spell when the player has used an item instead?  I would think that would only be done when a spell was used.

Comment: I have not finished everything I'm still working on the project. I just needed to fix that problem so I can build around it in the future.

Comment: Yes, but to deduct a spell cost means you need to know which spell was cast.  In the "use an item" branch, there is no spell chosen.  So you're trying to deduct the cost of a spell that isn't known.

Comment: Deducting spells works like this:

-User chooses a spell from the index == 1
-if spell.cost > current_mp (mp: magic points) it will say "not enough mp"
- if depending on what type of magic it is; black/white or dmg/aid the enemy will take or the player will heal based on the dmg value of the spell. there is a list of spells which is accessed through another set of indexes which is chosen and the values lie there.

Comment: basically the spells are determined what the second index the user chooses is.

Comment: Right.  What if the user instead chooses index == 2 first?  Then no spell is chosen, but you still try to deduct the cost.

Comment: There are only three instances where the user can enter a index. Menu, items, and magic. Both index == 2 is viable as a command to all menus. Items and magic index errors crash right now, but I plan to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. I needed the code to be below

```
spell = player.magic[magic_choice]
```